# Firebase error 500, Unable to resolve "firebase" from "firebase.js"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am trying to use firebase in my new React app but I am always getting "The development server returned response errror code: 500"

And I have no ideo of what am I doing wrong. I only created a firebase.js file to put my firebase configuration

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}


export {firebase};
```

I am getting this error in the terminal (and I am sure of having installed firebase):
`Unable to resolve "firebase" from "firebase.js"`

Comment: It should be `from "../relative-path-to-firebase.js"` and not just `"firebase.js". Otherwise it's looking for a Node package named `"firebase.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look right, you imported firebase never used it you created config never used it, is this the whole code ?

Please try to follow firebase documentation, last i checked you had to import only the *initializeApp* function with config object.

here this might help - [Firebase Setup for React App](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-crud-application-react-firebase-web-sdk-v9/#:%7E:text=Integrating%20Firebase%20into%20our%20React%20app&text=Copy%20the%20config%20to%20the,React%20app%2C%20create%20a%20firebase.)

Comment: Hey I found a solution by installing an other version of firebase and by reading expo firebase documentation. But thank you for your help